# VS2010 - Font colors for numbers in SQL scripts

Tags: visual-studio-2010, color-scheme

[sql script screenshot http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/74b768456c.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/74b768456c.png)

OK, see the numbers? I can barely see them because my Visual Studio 2010 theme has the backround as almost-black, and the numbers show up in the default color, which is black. I can't figure out which setting changes the color for a number in a .sql file. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Change the "Literal" and/or the "Number" color in Tools\Options...\Environment\Fonts and Colors.

Comment: Actually, it's the "Number" setting.

Comment: In my case it was set to Default (a light grey) changed to non-default silver and it worked.

Comment: For me, even though I had it set to "White" it was still showing black. I changed to another color and hit OK and it worked. Then I just went back and chose "White" again, as I wanted and it changed to white. Weird. It was somehow ignoring the setting until I updated it.

Comment: It was number, and thank you... the "default" was white on black... changing it worked.. :)

Comment: +1 @sergiopereira same thing happened to me, it should have been visible (and that's why I went right past the setting!)